# View Safari search history from terminal/bash

Tags: terminal

Is it possible to view the search history from a web browser in a terminal? I would like to know if you can do this on Mac or Linux. Thank you so much.

Comment: you can view Firefox's history: https://askubuntu.com/a/412890